# Implementing Pipeline Pattern, design and function pointer issue

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write my own solution of the pipe and filter pattern with threads, I'd like some input. My current issue is that the library I am using(tinythread) expects a global function pointer to start a thread :

```
thread  (void(*)(void *) aFunction, void * aArg )
```

My Stage class has a Process function that I wanted to pass as the function pointer.

```
class Stage
{
public:
    void Process(void *aArg);

protected:
    Stage(SharedBuffer *inPipe, SharedBuffer *outPipe);
    virtual void init() = 0;
    virtual bool work() = 0;
    virtual void finish() = 0;

protected:
    SharedBuffer *mInPipe;
    SharedBuffer *mOutPipe;
};
```

Implementation :

```
void Stage::Process(void * aArg)
{
    init();
    while(work());
    finish();
}
```

In my pipeline class I create each thread this way :

```
void Pipeline::Start()
{
    assert(mStages.size() > 0);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < mStages.size(); ++i)
    {
        tthread::thread t1(&mStages[i].Process, 0); //C2276
    }
}
```

I don't know if my design is flawed, I tried writing my own solution. My problem right now is that I can't seem to pass the function since it's a class member. It doesn't feel like it makes sense to me to have it as a static function since each Process call comes from a different sub-class of Stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Process` is a class method - it's not a member of the class, so your syntax for referencing it is incorrect. Also, as a class method, it has to be called on an instance of the class - so you need a way to actually do that.

Thankfully, it looks like the library allows you to pass in a context argument - which in your case should be your `Stage*`. So all you need to do is create a function matching the signature that the library expects that will do the right thing:

```
void CallProcess(void* stage) {
   static_cast<Stage*>(stage)->Process();
}
```

And pass that in:

```
tthread::thread t1(CallProcess   ,  &mStages[i]);
//                 void(*)(void*),  void*
```

Note that in C++11, we can actually create a thread to call `Process` directly:

```
std::thread t1(&Stage::Process, mStages[i]);
```